# Creating Custom Authorization Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a policy for authorizing a users access to a particular view. To authorize however I need to check the user against an id that is being passed to the action as a parameter. How can I access this in my authorize policy.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CanSeePage")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Page(int pageId)
{
```

How can I access this int 'caseId' in the CanSeePage.cs class.

Comment: That's a custom authorization attribute?  Show us the code.

Comment: Its a class that is extending the AuthorizationHandler class. I havent written the code yet, i just want to know how (if possible) to pass the parameter into the handler.

Comment: Solved the problem. Changed to ActionFilterAttribute and used (PageController)filterContext.Controller;